# String concatenation not working in HTML declaration of TABS through PHP variables

Tags: php, html, variables, tabs

The below code is not showing similar results as other one :

```
 <?php 
    $week = array('Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday');
    $k=0;
    while ( $k<= 6) {
    $t=$k+1;
    echo "<li>";
                echo "<a href=#panel-".$t." data-toggle='tab'>".$week[$k];
                echo "</a></li>";
                $k+=1;
        }
    $a=1;
    echo '<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane" id="panel-"'.$a.'>
                <div class="alert alert-info" role="alert">
                 <a href="#" class="alert-link">'.$week[$a].'Bazaars</a>
            </div>';
?>
```

Other One

```
<div class="tab-pane " id="panel-4">
  <div class="alert alert-info" role="alert">
        <a href="#" class="alert-link">Wednesday Bazaars- बुधवार बाजार</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

While Loop is **SAME** for both the cases

Comment: Please provide your expected result

Comment: Similar to how the content opens when we click on a respected tab, i want to add an array instead of writing the tabs 7 times using this PHP code !
It worked for Wednesday Bazaar "tab-pane" but not when I give the values using variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are missing "

```
//your code
echo '<div class="tab-pane" id="panel-"'.$a.'>';


///should be
echo '<div class="tab-pane" id="panel-'.$a.'">';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this,

```
 $week = array('Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday');
 foreach($week as $k => $v){

    echo "<li>";
    echo "<a href='#panel-".($k+1)."' data-toggle='tab'>".$v."</a>";
    echo "</li>";

  }
```

You href is missing "  '  " the single quote

Comment: Actually the problem is in next part of the code, the #panel is giving values to the wednesday code, but not the one in which I used variables\